# How to add series after click event in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hey I would like to add new series for every click event which occur, on each point of the graph.
So far I have succeeded only on adding a point to existing series.
How can I add multiple series on click event(when I click chart's points).
This is the jsfiddle so far:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    // find the clicked values and the series
                    var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                        y = e.yAxis[0].value,
                        series = this.series[0];

                    // Add it
                    series.addPoint([x,y]);
         

                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User supplied data'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        'click': function () {
                            if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                                this.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new series with a single point on each you just need to call `this.addSeries()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          this.addSeries({
            data: [ [e.xAxis[0].value, e.yAxis[0].value] ]
          });
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'User supplied data'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
    },
    xAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      minPadding: 0.2,
      maxPadding: 0.2,
      maxZoom: 60
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value'
      },
      minPadding: 0.2,
      maxPadding: 0.2,
      maxZoom: 60,
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        point: {
          events: {
            'click': function() {
              if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                this.remove();
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
        [20, 20],
        [80, 80]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `addSeries` function like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    // find the clicked values and the series
                    var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                        y = e.yAxis[0].value;
                    this.addSeries({                        
                      name: "new serie",
                      data: [[x, y], [x+10, y-10]]
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User supplied data'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        'click': function () {
                            if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                                this.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    // find the clicked values and the series
                    var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                        y = e.yAxis[0].value,
                        series = this.series[0];

                    // Add it
                    series.addPoint([x,y]);
         

                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User supplied data'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        'click': function () {
                            if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                                this.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I need to put only the points that I will add and put it in a series to calculate the regression line I do not need data: [[20,20], [80,80]].

Thank you.